# 'str' object has no attribute 'get' django error

Tags: django, authentication

I am creating a login form and after filling up the information it is showing 'str' object has no attribute 'get' error
views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth

# Create your views here.
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username= request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if user is not None:
           auth.login(request,user)
           return("home")
        else:
           messages.info(request,"invalid credentials")
           return redirect('login')

    else:
        return render(request,'buy/login.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening because of this line:

```
               return("home")
```

In order to return a string, you must use:

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse
```

And then,

```
               return HttpResponse("home")
```

**However**, maybe you wanted to redirect to a view called 'home', and mistakenly forgotten `redirect`.

In that case just correct your code to:

```
               return redirect("home")
```