# Django "'str' object has no attribute 'decode'" Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, google-app-engine

I'm not using any `decode` in my codes but I receive this error on Google Cloud Engine. However app is working fine on my local. And only Admin login page is loading on cloud but it fails after login with same error.

this is my view for the home page. ( Pagination is commented because it gives same error on pagination too)

```
def HomePage(request):
    id = 0
    post = Post.objects.filter(is_active=True).select_related('created_user').prefetch_related('category')
    # paginator = Paginator(post, 10)
    # page_obj = paginator.page(request.GET.get('page', '1'))

    context = {
        'posts': post # page_obj
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

This is the content of the one view for the including `setting.html`. The logic is same in others.

```
import traceback

from django import template
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

from .models import AppSettings
from django.db.models import Count
from django.http import HttpResponse

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('setting.html')
def get_base(base):
    try:
        appsetting = AppSettings.objects.filter(is_active=True) 
    except Exception as e:
        trace_back = traceback.format_exc()
        # message = str(e) + " " + str(trace_back)
    return {'appsettings': appsetting}
```

This is the code in the `setting.html` template for default web page settings

```
{% for s in appsettings %}
    <title>{{ s.title }}</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="{{ s.descr }}" />
    <meta name="robots" content="{{ s.robot }}" />
    <link rel="canonical" href="{{ s.canonical }}" />
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" /> 
    <meta property="og:description" content="{{ s.title }}" />  
{% endfor %}
```

I have changed below part in the `django\db\backends\mysql\operations.py`, but I see original line in the traceback. Also it doesn't allow me deploy with the original first line.

```
            # query = query.decode(errors='replace')
            query = errors='replace'
```

[image: Error Line 1]

[image: Error Line 2]
Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://flowing-my_server.appspot.com/index/

Django Version: 2.2.7
Python Version: 3.8.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'Blog']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /workspace/My_Site/templates/_base.html, error at line 0
   'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
   1 : {% load static %}
   2 : {% load sidebar %}
   3 : {% load category %}
   4 : {% load recent_post %}
   5 : {% load tag_cloud %}
   6 : {% load base %}
   7 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   8 : <html lang="en">
   9 : <head>
   10 :      {% get_base base %}


Traceback:

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/workspace/Blog/views.py" in HomePage
  284.     return render(request, 'index.html', context)

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  62.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  166.             len_values = len(values)

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  256.         self._fetch_all()

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1242.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  55.         results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1098.             cursor = self.connection.cursor()

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py" in cursor
  256.         return self._cursor()

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py" in _cursor
  233.         self.ensure_connection()

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py" in ensure_connection
  217.                 self.connect()

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py" in connect
  197.         self.init_connection_state()

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in init_connection_state
  231.         if self.features.is_sql_auto_is_null_enabled:

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __get__
  80.         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/features.py" in is_sql_auto_is_null_enabled
  82.             cursor.execute('SELECT @@SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL')

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  103.             sql = self.db.ops.last_executed_query(self.cursor, sql, params)

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/operations.py" in last_executed_query
  146.             query = query.decode(errors='replace')

Exception Type: AttributeError at /index/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: What is the purpose of returning `HttpResponse({'appsettings': appsetting})`?  What are you trying to return?  Are you trying to render a page?

Comment: I was not using HttpResponse but I applied it after saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63075120/str-object-has-no-attribute-get-django-error) Before this question it was `return {'appsettings': appsetting}` but still was giving same error.

Comment: What kind of response is that view _supposed_ to return?  A simple page render?  A JSON object?  A file download?  What?

Comment: I just added codes on how to use that data in the template.

Comment: You still haven't told us what kind of response that view is _supposed_ to return.  We can't help if you won't answer our questions.

Comment: Sorry I thought I answered. No JSON, very standard basic data reading `appsetting = AppSettings.objects.filter(is_active=True) ` getting data from AppSettings model and trying to print title, name and other settings for web page. Same as printing Posts.  Just this code is working in a different file but not in the views.py however I get same error with views.py even removing these templates.

Comment: If that view is supposed to provide a web page, the same as Posts, then why aren't you returning a `render()` call, as the other view does?

Comment: I can try but I was using this way because these templates are part of the _base.html and engine calls them default for all pages. I call that temple in the _base.html like this `<head> {% get_base base %}<link href="https://f....`

Comment: After rendering like usual, it gives `'str' object has no attribute 'META'`, and not working even on my local now. Do you think it is an improvement or irrelevant?

Comment: Update the question to show the changed code.

Comment: just did for the part changed.

Comment: Check that your local environment and the cloud environment have the same Python and packages installed. The error is happening in the MySQL database driver, where it's expecting the query being built is a `bytes`, but is instead a `str`. It's probably an issue of locally running Python 2, and in the cloud running Python 3.

Comment: I tried to compare but couldn't find a way to check on the cloud server. I chose python38 in my app.yaml, it is the version I have on my local. `runtime: python38 
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :8080 My_Site.wsgi
env: standard`. I also created [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65396976/django-gives-502-bad-gateway-error-on-google-app-engine) during deploy and It seem, I fixed it in some way, that's I couldn't keep track

Comment: May I ask why you put base as a parameter to the template tag get_base but it is not set in the context of the view/html ... so empty ?

Comment: I'm not much good with Django. I found that structure a time ago and using that after that time.